# QGIS Clip of layer with several points

Tags: qgis, clip

I have two shapefiles:
1) one with several points with a buffer around each separated point
2) another which is a single polygon with several characteristics (therefore it has several polygons inside, with different sizes).

What I want to do:
I want to perform a "clip" and obtain the characteristics of the single polygon (2) within each point in (1).

This is what it looks like before the "clip":
[image]

And this is what is looks like after the "clip":
[image]

What I get is all the points together, but what I wanted was for them to be individual as well. How do I do that? Does anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool that you are probably searching for is called "intersect" from "vector"-"geoprocessing". Your points will be the input features and the polygons the second, cutting layer. The outcome will be points with the attributes of the original points and underlying polygons. If this is not what you wanted please consider editing your question for clearance on the task.

Comment: It is working now; that is the tool I need, thank you very much!